# Rails has_many through a HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have three models, User, Team, and Game. Currently constructed as such.

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'home_team_id'
    has_many :away_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'away_team_id'
    has_many :wins, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'winner_id'
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_many :teams_owned, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many :games, through: :teams
end
```

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: "Team", optional: true
end
```

I want to add an association between users and games. So I can call User.games and Game.users.

I tried adding this:

```
#in user model
has_many :games, through: :teams

#in team model
has_many :games, ->(team) { where('home_team_id = ? or away_team_id = ?', team.id, team.id) }, class_name: 'Game'
```

As the [api docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3A%3AAssociations%3A%3AClassMethods-label-Customizing+the+query) said to do. But, when I try to call this association, I get an error that "game.team_id does not exist". Since each game has a home_team_id and away_team_id, but no team_id.

Did I just implement this extremely poorly? Or am I missing something? Any help appreciated.

Comment: which line is giving the error?

Comment: @JoelBlum when I try to call User.games

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this isn't a really good solution.

In ActiveRecord you can't actually define associations where the foreign key can potentially be in two different columns like this:

```
has_many :games, ->(team) { where('home_team_id = ? or away_team_id = ?', team.id, team.id) }, class_name: 'Game'
```

It definitely won't work as Rails will still join the assocation as `JOIN games ON games.team_id = teams.id`. Just adding a `WHERE` clause to the query won't fix that. Since ActiveRecord actually creates a variety of different queries there is no option to simply provide a different join.

A kludge to make this work would be to add an instance method:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  def users
    User.joins(:teams)
        .where(teams: { id: home_team.id })
        .or(Team.where(id: away_team.id))
  end
end
```

As its not an actual association you cant join through it or use an sort of eager loading to avoid n+1 queries.

If you actually want to create a single association that you can join through you would need to add a join table between games and teams.

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :game_teams
  has_many :games, through: :game_teams
end

# rails g model game_team team:belongs_to game:belongs_to score:integer 
class GameTeam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :game
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :game_teams
  has_many :users, through: :teams
end
```

This is a better idea since it gives you a logical place to record the score per team.

As an aside if the composition of teams can change and accurate record keeping is important you might actually need additional join tables as the lineup when a game is played may not actually match the current lineup.

Comment: On a second note HABTM is effing useless. You want to use `has_many through:` instead pretty much always. https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: The composition of a team can change. But, I don't need to keep track of the composition of the team for historic games. 

I still want to explicitly know who the home team and away team are. Would the best solution be to add a 'is_home_team' column to the GameTeam join table? That is what I'm leaning towards right now.

Comment: Yes, thats an option. I would use an enum column on PG instead of boolean though as it makes more sense to query `SELECT game_teams WHERE played_at = 'away'` rather then `is_home_team = 0`.

Comment: dope. accepting this very helpful answer. If I did want to start tracking historic data for what players were on a team for a given game, I assume I would have to create an explicit UserGame table/model instead of relying on a through relationship.

Comment: Yes. You would need a triple join table with columns for user_id, team_id and game_id.

Comment: One last question. Let's say I wanted to record "attendance", as in whether a player is able to make it to a certain game. Would it make more sense for me to create a UserGame, in addition to the other join tables, or just create a triple join table.

Comment: It depends slightly on how its going to be queried / used. If you have a large number of players per team and many of them are absent in each game you might want to use two tables instead of just one table with anther flag on it.